# How can I catch a link trigger so that I can pass a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a client's website and they want it to be bilangual. It's based on wordpress and I purchase WPML plugin. Now, I want to add a language switch button but I can't do this while still being able to customize and insert it wherever I want so I came up with a solution:

The page render with content translated only when the url meet the parameter "?lang=en" so if the url is "www.website.com/page" it will be normally rendered and if the url is "www.website.com/page?lang=en" it's content will be in english.

I came up with the solution of make the custom switch buttons with the href according to this scheme. However, once he choose a language I want it to maintain while browsing through the website.

Now, how can I make the website to work in that way that if his current page containt "?lang=en" in url, when he access another page to pass this parameter? So far, I was able to check if a page containt this parameter and now I don't know how to pass it (I'm talking of doing that in javascript with jquery).

Comment: I'd suggest you use session variables on the server side to store language settings instead of having to manually append to every single URL that the user could possibly visit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing it in a session variable would probably be best but since you asked you can parse the query string generically like below. If you have anything after the `#` you may want to `split()` that off as well (`queryStr = queryStr.split('#')[0];`).

```
function parseQuery(url) {
    var queryStr = url ? url.split('?')[1] : location.search.slice(1),
        query = {};
    if (queryStr !== '') {
        var params = queryStr.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var param = params[i].split('=');
            query[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = decodeURIComponent(param[1] || '');
         }
    }        
    return query;
}
```